# How to extract part of a string?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get file name without the extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924394/how-to-get-file-name-without-the-extension)

I have a list of xml files and I'm trying to return just the file name without the extension.
For example, if I have:

```
String filename = "hello.xml";
```

How would I return just "hello" with the fact the file names vary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String filenameSansExt = filename.replaceAll("\\.[^.]*", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `substring()` is more efficient rather than using `replaceAll()` with regex, or any other regex.

Both answers are not quite satisfactory:

- regex is too slow, but correct
- `lastIndexOf()` will throw an exception when `'.'` is not there (index `-1`)

Correct answer has to check index of `lastIndexOf()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the substring function for strings in java. You would start at 0 (the beginning of the string) and end before the 4th to last character (".")

```
String filename = "hello.xml";
String filename2 = filename.substring(0, filename.length() - 4);
```

Comment: what happens when there is no extension or the extension is longer than 3 characters + a `.`? Not to mention filenames that are < 4 characters?