# How to read and split file text based on extension?

Tags: java

Hi in java I am trying to split a text file [data.txt]which contains:

```
abc.txt  
hello.jpg  
play.mp4  
image.jpg  
text.txt
```

...

name of files in text form. and now i want to split this file based on file extension such as .mp3, .txt, .jpg etc using java program. because later on i want to execute that files with diffrent program based on the extention or filetype.

I have created a sample program but i am not getting how to split it based on extension

sample program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class RF
{
   public void readFile()
   {
    try
    {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("data.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    while((strLine = br.readLine())!=null)
    {

        String[] splitted = strLine.split(" ");

        for( String s : splitted)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }


    }
    in.close();

    } catch(Exception e)
     {

     }
   }
}

public class FileSplit
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        RF r = new RF();
        r.readFile();



    }
   }
```

I want output as :

```
output 
abc is a text file 
hello is a image file
play is a mp4 file
image is a image file
text is a text file
```

Thanks.

Comment: Tip: Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Comment: Try read this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: You keep using the word "split" but you are describing filtering.  Do you want to find entries in the file based on a pattern (e.g. find file names ending in "txt")?

Comment: yes i want filtering based on pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Check this statement

```
strLine.split("-");
```

you are splitting on the wrong delimiter

Answer (score 1):

Try spliting by the delimiter `"\\."`:

```
String[] splitted;
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    splitted = strLine.split("\\.");

    System.out.println(splitted[0]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
abc
hello
play
image
text
```

**Note:**

The extensions are stored in `splitted[1]` each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

kurumi pointed out that you are using the wrong delimiter. You need to use

```
strLine.split(".");
```

Even with the "." delimiter your code will not consider special cases where filename itself has a "." in it. you are better off using a standard library like "FilenameUtils". Please refer to the following.
[How to get the filename without the extension in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924394/how-to-get-file-name-without-the-extension)