# How to display name of the files without extensions and in alphabetical order

Tags: java, android, file

I have this script which allow to display inside a list view, the name of the files located in a specific folder.

I would like to know if is possible adapt this script to display the files without the extension and in alphabetical order.
Thank you

```
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/osmdroid/tiles/");
    File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
    String[] theNamesOfFiles = new String[filelist.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < theNamesOfFiles.length; i++) {
       theNamesOfFiles[i] = filelist[i].getName();
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_row, theNamesOfFiles);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get file name without the extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924394/how-to-get-file-name-without-the-extension)

Comment: For the alphabetical order you could use [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/osmdroid/tiles/");
File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
String[] theNamesOfFiles = new String[filelist.length];
for (int i = 0; i < theNamesOfFiles.length; i++) {
   //do a little change
   String temp = filelist[i].getName();
   theNamesOfFiles[i] = temp.substring(0,temp.length() - temp.lastIndexOf("."));
}
Arrays.sort(theNamesOfFiles)
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_row, theNamesOfFiles);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Hello Dian. Your code work perfectly to sort names in alphabetical order. For the file extensions, it just remove the last letter

Comment: seems that can not return more than 4 letters per string

Answer (score 0):

To order your file list array in alphabetical  order you can use sort() static method of Arrays:

```
Arrays.sort(filelist);
```

And to remove extension you can use:

```
fileName = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(fileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately seems that i don't have this apache package in Eclipse