# How to get only the filename from filepath in javafx

Tags: javafx, substring

If the filepath is `"OperatingSystem/Terminal/Terminal.txml"`,How can I only get the Filename without extension in javafx?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924394/how-to-get-file-name-without-the-extension) helps you.

Comment: Okey,Thank you,Is those answers okey for javafx too,coz I'm new to javafx,that's why I ask this question

Comment: For example, the second answer provides a solution with a regular expression, which is totally fine for javafx.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JavaFX. It is a pure Java issue.