# case-sensitive processing of file names

Tags: java, file

Looking to verify that there's no case-sensitive methods for processing file/path references.

This is for a use like looking up a file with a ".pdf" and/or ".PDF" extension in the directory without knowing whether it is upper- or lower-case.

`java.nio.file.Files` doesn't seem to have it. the only way I can think of is checking both cases or using `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` at it.

is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe `FileUtils.listFiles(theDir, new String[]{"pdf", "PDF" }, ...)` with `FileUtils` from [apache-commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean)) ?

Comment: @RC cant upvote your comment. the ans gets it.

Comment: So the question was "How to remove the extension from a filename?", according to the accepted answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use external jar like apache-commons , and read file without caring of extension type or case sensitivity

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
String fileNameWithOutExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(fileNameWithExt);
```

There also other ways will help you there :[How to get the filename without the extension in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924394/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [a `FileNameFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list-java.io.FilenameFilter-), something like:

```
File folder = Paths.get("/path/to/folder").toFile();
String[] pdfs = folder.list((dir, name) -> name.endsWith(".pdf") || name.endsWith(".PDF"));
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Files::list`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
Files.list(Paths.get("c:/temp"))
     .filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".pdf") ||
                  p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".PDF"))
```

You can then act on the stream or collect it into a list for example.