# How to invoke substring(int, int) on the array type String[] in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a file name reader from a folder.file`s names taken into a string array.what i want is when i executed this code segment i want the file name without its extension. But still extensions get printed out.

```
import java.io.File;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file=new File("D:\\C_App\\PDF");
        String[] files = file.list();
        for(String string : files) {
            string.substring(0, string.length());
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Just so you ALL know...A file name doesn't necessarily need to contain a file name extension. NONE of your answers takes this into account. @D.Anush - Check out the thread in [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924394/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-in-java).

Comment: Strings are immutable in java. The `substring` method returns a **new** string that you need to assign to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("D:\\SunilKanjar");
    String[] files = file.list();
    for (String string : files) {
        if (string.lastIndexOf(".") > 0) {
            System.out.println(string.substring(0, string.lastIndexOf(".")));
        }
    }
}
```

To get file name without extension first of all we need to find is there any extension or not and then need to remove extension only and for that find `.` at from the last.

It is not accurate to assume that file name not contain more then one `.` sign.

Answer (score 1):

Take substring of string from the last index of `.`

```
import java.io.File;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file=new File("D:\\C_App\\PDF");
        String[] files = file.list();
        for(String string : files) {
             if(new File(string).isFile){ 
               if (string.lastIndexOf(".") > 0) {
                  System.out.println(string.substring(0, a.lastIndexOf('.'));
               }
            else {
               System.out.println(string);
            }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at Main.main(Main.java:9). im very new to programming pls help

Comment: Can you print file name?

Comment: No nothing prints out except that exception.

Comment: Do `System.out.println(string);` and tell me the output.

Comment: File name get printed out with the extension.

Comment: Yes. show me that output. Can you add that into your question?

Comment: @D.Anush I have updated my answer. Which will now check for the string is file or folder.

Comment: This is a valid file name in the Windows OS: `te..........st.txt`.

Comment: @Kaustubh I build my answer with the help you provided. thanks

Comment: @DevilsHnd updated answer. thanks

Comment: @D.Anush i have updated answer to support DevilsHnd's point.

Comment: @Kaustubh - Now work on the fact that a file name doesn't necessarily need to contain a file name extension.

Answer (score 0):

using regex by matching the last dot ( `.` ) and split,

the regex `(\\.)(?!.*\\.)` matches the last dot.

```
import java.io.File;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file=new File("D:\\C_App\\PDF");
    String[] files = file.list();
    for(String string : files) {
      if (!string.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(string.split("(\\.)(?!.*\\.)")[0]);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be the route I would of taken however I would of also added: `if (new File(string).isDirectory()) { continue; }` to ignore directories names within the list.

Comment: @D.Anush can you mark it an answer if it answers your question?