# Add date to my file name before any extension

Tags: java

I want to add date to filename just before the file extension.

For example

Input : **test.txt** or **test.png**

Output : **test-02-Feb-2018_13:05:17-am.txt** or **test-02-Feb-2018_13:05:17-am.png**

Note: anytype not txt only

Comment: Please make a complete sentence and explain what you are trying to do. What are your inputs and expected outputs? What did you try?

Comment: i want to upload file i want to add date to filename what ever file type 
how to add date to filename

Comment: @StuDev Rather than post clarifications as comments, edit the text of your Question.

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Comment: Tips: Learn about "basic" variations of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. `OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'" ) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option is (assuming you always have an extension) is to get the last index of `.` and use [`String::substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) to get the parts of the filename you need, and insert the timestamp of choice.

For example, something you could use and manipulate to your liking:

```
String filename = "test.txt";
System.out.println(filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf(".")) + LocalDateTime.now() + filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".")));
```

**Output:**

> test2019-01-21T15:20:34.992.txt

Comment: Never use `LocalDateTime` when tracking an actual moment. Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, this class cannot represent a moment, by definition. Use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime` for a moment. You can get away with using `LocalDateTime` here, but doing so is misleading and confusing.

Comment: @BasilBourque good point - it was more to just give an example of how to put something with a timestamp in there but I see where you're coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You should extract base file name and extension from the file, and then reconstruct the file name by adding the date.

This two links should help you :

[How do I get the file extension of a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java)

[How to get the filename without the extension in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924394/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-in-java)

I suppose you already know how to format a date

Comment: You should mark as duplicate or else put relevant details in your answer, not links to other answers.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. By quoting these questions, I give him some clue, without giving the answer which is not the goal here. I added an introduction to my answer to make it more clear.