# How to extract a subString from android java String?

Tags: java, android, string, substring

I tried to extract Sub-String from java string, but failed. i tried like this

```
String text = "audios/{any_number} any_audio_name.mp3";
text= text.substring(text.indexOf('/'), text.indexOf('3')-2);
```

**Updated**

I need String contains only **`any_audio_name`** and removing **`audios/`** , any number e.g. **`{123}`** and **`.mp3`**

For example **`audios/{211} new school poem.mp3`** to **`new school poem`**

Comment: What do you mean by failed? Did you get an error?

Comment: If you don't want to include the `/`, use `text.indexOf('/')+1`. And better to use `lastIndexOf('.')` than relying on subtracting 2.

Comment: If you're working with file names, Apache Commons has [FileNameUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) that do the hard work for you and would scale better.

Comment: Regex is overkill ... anyway, duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924394/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Use regex seems fit here.

```java
public class MyMain{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String line = "audios/any_audio_name.mp3";
        String pattern = "audios\\/(.*)\\.mp3";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"^.*/(.*)\\..*$"` would fit more cases. You can't use `\/`, it's either `\\/` or `/`. And use `group(1)`.

Comment: String pattern = "audios\/(.*).mp3"; give "Illegal escape character in string literal" error

Comment: I/System.out: NO MATCH

Comment: Simpler to just use replace, e.g. `text = text.replaceFirst("^(?:.*?/)?([^/]+?)(?:\\.[^./]*?)?$", "$1");` --- See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6sz0lj/1) on regex101

Comment: @Andreas if text contains like audios/{123} audio_name.mp3 and i need just name like audio_name what will i do???

Comment: @Attaullah 1) Learn regex. 2) Update the pattern in the replace call.

Comment: Pattern miss some java string in List. when Capital MP3 instead of mp3 @Andreas

Comment: @Attaullah Since [my pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56367130/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-android-java-string/56367224?noredirect=1#comment99337877_56367224) doesn't specify `mp3`, it cannot care about lower- vs upper-case, so it simply cannot match differently just because `.mp3` is changed to `.MP3`. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might helpful

```
String text = "audios/any_audio_name.mp3";
text= text.substring(text.indexOf('/')+1, text.indexOf('.'));
```

Comment: this also work but previous one give me answer first

Comment: You'd probably want to use `lastIndexOf` for both of them. Whether changing that or not, you should also cross your fingers and hope to never see input like `foo.bar/file_without_extension`

Comment: Yes you correct but in here his requirement is to get name of mp3 file.so most probably that file come with .mp3 extention and he describe file path as audios

Comment: Actually i read XML data is in server in listview, first i filtered (whole line into name) and then showing it in listview.

Answer (score 1):

For Your Edited Question.Following Code segment will help you but here i assume that there will be no number within "any_audio_name"

```
String text = "audios/{any_number}any_audio_name.mp3";
text= text.substring(text.indexOf('/')+1, text.indexOf('.')).replaceAll("[\\d.]", "");;
```

Comment: but {} is remaining

Comment: .replaceAll("\\{|\\}|[\\d.]",""); is use this

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone, who give me idea for solving this issue.

```
 String text = "audios/{any_number}any_audio_name.mp3";
 text= text.substring(text.indexOf('/')+1, text.indexOf('.')).replaceAll("\\{|\\}|[\\d.]","");
 System.out.println(text);
```